# How to disable AO on smooth edges, but keep it enabled on sharp edges?

Tags: edges

I'm creating a scene, and I really like to use AO, because it adds some bonus detail to the final render. But in most of the cases it ruins the smooth feeling for smooth edges. I have marked sharp edges everywhere, where I wanted sharp edges, to make sure they will look just cool, and the AO looks good on them, not like on smooth edges. I'll attach a few examples:

[image: As you can see, it ruins the "smooth" feeling.][image: Here you can see, that there is no "sharp edge" marked there, unlike the edges.]

Answer (score 1):

Adding an *EdgeSplit* modifier before a *Subdivision Surface* instead of doing autosmooth seems to alleviate the problem. Dirty, I know...

[image: Autosmooth]
[image: EdgeSplit + SubSurf]

Comment: Is there any way to make it without increasing the poly-count? Subdividing everything wouldn't be too good for me.

Comment: I know, but I didn't find another way. You could of course always switch to cycles, which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: If I switch to cycles, do I have to re-do everything to make it look as it did in default Blender, except the AO?

Comment: If by everything you mean the materials, yes. Modelling stays the same. You can try it, it's not destructive, and see what you lose.